# How to implement MPI_Comm in MPI protocol?

Tags: c, mpi

I am trying to implement the MPI protocol in EPOS Operation System. Well, in fact I didn't understand how to implement the MPI_Comm. It is defined as "basic object used by MPI to determine which processes are involved in a communication". In some implementations that
I found on Internet it is implemented as **typedef int MPI_Comm**, but how could I know
which process are involved in a communication using ***int* MPI_Comm**? Any idea?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There seem to be two approaches, which are almost the same.

- The first is to `typedef int MPI_Comm`, and use the value as an index into some internal data structure that maintains the actual information.
- The second is to `typedef struct comm_info* MPI_Comm` where the communicator (or any other MPI type) is a direct pointer to the internal structure. OpenMPI takes this approach.

The advantage of using an int is that it might be easier to use the same indices on all processors as long as the internal data struct is synchronized.

But why re-invent the wheel when OpenMPI and MPICH already do so much and are open source? The MPICH license in particular is extremely permissive. So much so that quite a few of the vendors base their own commercial MPI libraries on it. Check out [their license](http://git.mpich.org/mpich.git/blob_plain/6aab201f58d71fc97f2c044d250389ba86ac1e3c:/COPYRIGHT).

Comment: Thanks! Well, It is a work of Operating Systems course so a need to make my own implementation version. Other doubt: my implementation will have a internal data structure (let say 'x') that contains each ID processes that are involved in a communication (using MPI_Comm, for example). If there are lots of machines running a MPI program and I want these machines communicating with each other, how I will save in 'x' the ID of the each MPI program? And each MPI program will have its own 'x', so it would be a problem?

Comment: @user2069668 Apart from the built-in communicators like `MPI_COMM_WORLD`, the user must first create the communicator using `MPI_Comm_create`. You can put your initializations there. Remember that it's also up to the user to have all processors in that communicator call `MPI_Comm_create` at the "same" time and with the same parameters. That should allow you to initialize your struct without passing any messages by having every processor come up with the same struct 'x'.

Answer (score 0):

When an implementation uses an int for an MPI_Comm, it's actually using it as a reference to an internal array where it keeps track of all of the necessary information for the communicator internally.